# Functional languages type inference confusion

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, type-inference

Suppose I have this code in ocaml:

```
# let func a b = b a;;
val func : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
```

The function type makes sense since we can see that in the rhs, `b` is a function that takes `a` as the argument so that the type of `b` is  `('a ->'b)`, so that also implies the result is of type `'b` and type of a is `'a`. So we get `val func : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>`.

However, what I not get is

```
# let func a b c = a b c;;
val func : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c = <fun>
```

Following the logic in the first problem, its clear in the rhs `a` is a function that takes in `b` and `c`, and `b` is also a function that takes `c`. So obviously the type of `a` is `('a->'b->'c)` and also the type of `b` is `('a->'b)` and the type of `c` is just `'a`. So the function type I get is `(type of a) -> (type of b) -> (type of c) -> result` and substituting the above logic I get `('a -> 'b ->'c) -> ('a ->'b) -> 'a -> 'c` but that is obviously not what the true type of `func` is. Can someone explain what is wrong with my logic?

Also, If I were to write `let func a b c = a b c` without any sugar would it be `let func = fun a -> fun b -> (fun c -> a b c)` ? thank you

Comment: I think you were confused about order of operations: `a b c` is `(a b) c`, not `a (b c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said in the question : “and `b` is also a function that takes `c`”

This is the part where your reasoning is going wrong. This is not a constraint that exist. It looks superficially like `b` is applied to `c` but it's not, it's just the second argument of `a` whereas `c` is the third argument of `a`.

It may be clearer that `b` is never applied to `c` if you make precedence explicit with some parentheses:

```
# let func a b c = (a b) c;;
val func : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c = <fun>
```

If you had written `let func a b c = ignore (b c) ; a b c;;`, then `b` would be a function that is applied to `c`. In this case the reasoning would apply and you would have:

```
# let func a b c = ignore (b c) ; a b c;;
val func : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
```

Your second question is:

> Also, If I were to write `let func a b c = a b c` without any sugar would it be `let func = fun a -> fun b -> (fun c -> a b c)`

Yes, the former is just a concise notation for the latter. The parentheses are not even necessary:

```
# let func = fun a -> fun b -> fun c -> a b c;;
val func : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c = <fun>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "obviously" is in fact wrong, at least as far as you're thinking about the types of `b` and `c`.  It might be clearer if you rename the type variables slightly differently:

```
# let func a b c = a b c;;
val func : ('b -> 'c -> 'd) -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd = <fun>
```

which is the same, just starting a `'b` for the names of the type variables.  Now it perhaps a bit clearer: the type of `a` is `'b -> 'c -> 'd` while the type of `b` is `'b` and the type of `c` is `'c`.  The function takes three arguments, passes the latter two (`b` and `c`), to the first argument (`a`) and returns what it returns (a value of type `'d`)